# Displaying Dot(.) Causes Error in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5. Now I stored some values in database tables which i want to retrive. Some of those values are floating point numbers. so when i fetch those values its giving me this error

```
   htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View:/home/vagrant/Code/Laravel_new/resources/views/product/create.blade.php)
```

It looks like because there is .(dot) in value it interpreat as a array instead of a sting. If I remove dot(.) form the data it works normally.
So any suggestion?

```
create.blade.php
<label>product
                    <select name="detail">
                        @foreach($product['core_detail']['detail'] as $id => $detail)
                            @if($id === Input::old('detail',array("hola"))))
                                <option value="{{$id}}" selected>{{$detail}}</option>
                            @else
                                <option value="{{$id}}">{{$detail}}</option>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                    {{ $errors->first('detail') }}
                </label>
```

Comment: Can you show the code from create.blade.php?

Comment: try {!! $detail !!} it will not escape anything

Comment: @umefarooq getting  Array to string conversion Error

Comment: You replaced both instances of {{$detail }} with {!! $detail !!}? Assuming $detail is the value with the dot

Comment: @nextt1 you have check $detail is array or string just do dd($detail); within loop

Comment: Yes I did and still if I remove dot from tables it works otherwise it's giving array to string conversion error

Comment: @umefarooq its an array i checked using dd(detail)

Comment: @umefarooq i used &#46; code for peroid(dot/.) and {{{$detail}}} and it worked

Comment: @aethergy its wokring now

Comment: Good to know! Glad you got it working.